# MySQL format time with lowercase am/pm

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a better way to format a time field to have a lowercase AM or PM? This is what I have in my SELECT statement and it works but it is rather clunky:

```
CONCAT_WS('', DATE_FORMAT(time, '%l:%i '), LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%p'))) AS time
```

I guess more importantly is there any significant overhead associated with formatting using SQL functions like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can directly do it without concactenation.

```
LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(`time`,'%l:%i %p'))
```

**[SEE HERE @ SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0935/5)**